# Queen movement in chess game(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function-pointers, prototypal-inheritance, chess

I am learning Javascript and as a project assignment making chess game in it. I have coded the logic for movement of Rook, Pawn, Knight and Bishop. Now I am stuck on Queen movement. A queen's move basically involves movement logic of Bishop and Rook.

What I want to do is when the Queen is moved check whether the [file](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/naming-ranks-and-files-in-chess.html) of source tile is same as destination tile. If it is same the invoke the code movement logic of Rook else invoke that of Bishop. For example, if queen is placed at d4 (source tile) and is either moved to d8 or g4(destination tile). Then in this case the Rook's move function should be invoked.

All the piece objects have a move() in it. So in this case I want to invoke move() of Rook from Queen's move(). I'm stuck here. Kindly suggest. The relevant code is pasted below. I have similarly made Rook and other objects. Now from this move() of Queen() I want to invoke move() of Rook/Bishop.

```
        chess.QueenFactory =
            {
                instance: function(color, type)
                {
                    var Queen =
                            {
                                move: function(color, type)
                                {
                                    alert("In Queen");
                                }
                            };
                    createPiece.call(Queen, color, type);
                    return Queen;
                }
            };
```

My move function of Bishop is placed in like this

```
chess.BishopFactory = 
{
    instance: function(color, type) 
    {
        var Bishop =
        {
            move: function(source, destn) 
            { //Code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to invoke this function from Queen's move(). How do I do that?

Please find the entire code at html link below.

https://github.com/varunpaprunia/ChessInJavascript/blob/master/ChessBoard_Tags_1.html

Comment: Place the relevant code in your question.

Comment: `x = 'abcdefgh'.indexOf(destination_tile[0]), y = parseInt(destination_tile[1]) - 1;` let `a, b` be the same for `source_tile`, respectively. A queen can move such that `a + b === x + y` (bottom left, top right), `a - x === b - y` (top left, bottom right), `a === x` (top to bottom) or `b === y` (left to right).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following tests to decide which method to use

```
// source tile
var a = 'abcdefgh'.indexOf(source_tile[0]), // 0 to 7
    b = parseInt(source_tile[1]) - 1;       // 0 to 7
// destination tile
var x = 'abcdefgh'.indexOf(dest_tile[0]),   // 0 to 7
    y = parseInt(dest_tile[1]) - 1;         // 0 to 7
// test to see how it's moving
if (a + b === x + y || a - x === b - y) {   // bLeft to tRight || tLeft to bRight
    // queen is moving like a bishop
} else if ( a === x || b === y) {           // top to bottom || left to right
    // queen is moving like a rook
} else {                                    // impossible move
    // invalid move
}
```

You can see from the comments where to invoke which follow-up. If `a === x && b === y` then `source_tile === dest_tile`, which doesn't count as moving the piece. These won't check if the paths are blocked, you'd need more logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do :

```
function bishopFn(source, destn){ /* bishop move */}
function rookFn(source, destn){ /* rook move */ }
```

then assign them to the bishop and rook move objects and in the queen's you just have to call any depending on whatever your condition is

```
move: function(source, destn){
    /* condition construction can be done here */
    if (/*condition*/) bishopFn(source, destn);
    else rookFn(source, destn);
}
```